# How do I check what applications are running in the background

Tags: android, kotlin

I am launching an application from my app and I need to know if it is running in the background or not. Here is what I've tried:

```
val activityManager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
val processes = activityManager.runningAppProcesses
for (processInfo in processes) {
    if (processInfo.processName == packageName) {
        return true
    }
}
return false
```

This doesn't work. It only shows my app in the list of processes. This used to be the way this was done but it appears the syntax has changed and I can't find the answer.

Edit: My use case is I am launching an app with intent to log the user in and I want to avoid the time it takes to log in unless it is absolutely necessary. So if app is running, just launch the app. If not, launch it with intent to log in.

Comment: This hasn't been practical in years for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Alright well I need to be able to tell if an app is open so I can decide on what intent to launch.

Comment: Contact the developers of the app, explain your situation, and ask them for advice. You cannot tell if an arbitrary app is open, for privacy and security reasons.